# slash bar added at the end of the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use a flat-file CMS called Sitecake. To load it, I have to upload a few file on my website, and add a few classes to my html. When done, I should access to the editing mode by adding /sitecake.php at the end of my url.

The problem is that my hosting service (one.com), or I don't know what else, is adding a "slash bar" (/) at the end of the url : /sitecake.php**/**

I tried a few things :

- upload, re-upload and re-re-upload the cms
- uploaded the website with the cms on another server, provided by another hosting service : perfectly working : http://guillaumeb.ch/peterwatkins/sitecake.php
- contacted the hosting service. They don't know where the problem
  comes from
- tried two different methodes to remove the '/' with my .htaccess file :

1.

> RewriteEngine on 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

2.

> $site = preg_replace('{/$}', '', $site);

Both are removing the '/', but also giving an error :

1. page not working ...
2. 500 internal error

What could I do next?

Comment: 500 internal error - That's a server error. If you have access to logs, see what's in there and then add it to your question.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for you answer. Not sure how I can access to logs ? Sorry about that.

Comment: Most hosts (if you're on a hosted site) offer access to logs; there should be something in there. If not, then see if you can add error reporting to your code and see what comes of it. Consult the following link http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: God... I can't believe it...

It seems like PHP 7.0 was the problem. I changed it to 5.6, and everything is working fine now...

Thanks everyone !

Comment: Glad to hear everything worked out, *cheers*